# Modifying Powershell LDAPFilter to add enabled=true

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've built a filter to look for a number of AD fields and properties that works well until I try to add a section looking for `'enabled -eq $true.'`

Here is the filter that works successfully:

```
$filter = "(&(msExchMailboxguid=*)"+"(facilityID=12345)"+"(|(jobCodeID=0001)"+"(jobCodeID=0002)"+"(jobCodeID=0003)(jobCodeID=0004)"+"(jobCodeID=0005)"+"(jobCodeID=0006)))"

Get-ADUser -SearchBase "dc=acme,dc=corp" -LDAPFilter $filter
```

This works, and produces the correct AD user objects (four total).

But if I try looking for enabled accounts only, like so:

```
$filter = "(&(msExchMailboxguid=*)"+"(facilityID=12345)"+"(enabled=$true)"+"(|(jobCodeID=0001)"+"(jobCodeID=0002)"+"(jobCodeID=0003)(jobCodeID=0004)"+"(jobCodeID=0005)"+"(jobCodeID=0006)))"
```

It either fails with "the search filter can not be recognized," or it returns nothing at all depending on whether there are 3 or 4 closed parentheses.  I've tried a bunch of variations like `(enabled=true)`, `(enabled -eq true)` but none of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using an [LDAP filter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) which is different than a native PowerShell filter and so has a different syntax. Even though most LDAP fields match pretty closely to their normal names, the Enabled field is not stored as a "normal" property (e.g. boolean true/false). Instead, it is held in a part of a bitmasked property `userAccountControl`. That means you have to use the "intuitive" filter:

```
(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))
```

To filter out only the enabled accounts.

So that makes your filter for your example to become:

```
$filter = "(&(msExchMailboxguid=*)"+"(facilityID=12345)"+"(!(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2))"+"(|(jobCodeID=0001)"+"(jobCodeID=0002)"+"(jobCodeID=0003)(jobCodeID=0004)"+"(jobCodeID=0005)"+"(jobCodeID=0006)))"
```

Comment: Ok, this worked, thanks.  What a strange concept, bitmasked properties...